# R functions of shp

Tags: r, file, shapes

I'm trying to read my shapefile in R and still getting an error message

I installed these libraries

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

mydata<-st_read("C:/Users/User/Documents/PlotLocations_HARV.shp",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I got this error message:

```
Cannot open data source C:\Users\User\Documents\PlotLocations_HARV.shp
Error in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, as.character(options), quiet, type,  : 
  Open failed.
In addition: Warning message:
In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, as.character(options), quiet, type,  :
  GDAL Error 4: Unable to open C:\Users\User\Documents\PlotLocations_HARV.shx or C:\Users\User\Documents\PlotLocations_HARV.SHX.Try --config SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX true to restore or create it
```

I have the entire file as well
aoi_boundary_HARV <- st_read("C:\Users\rhusein\Documents\NEONDSSiteLayoutFiles\NEON-DS-Site-Layout-Files\HARV\HarClip_UTMZ18.shp")

and still getting the error message

Error in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, as.character(options), quiet, type, : Open failed. – julia 1 hour ago

Verify that the file PlotLocations_HARV.shx exists in the same folder as PlotLocations_HARV.shp

yes both are in the folder

now I am good thanks

Comment: I have the entire file as well

Comment: aoi_boundary_HARV <- st_read("C:\\Users\\rhusein\\Documents\\NEONDSSiteLayoutFiles\\NEON-DS-Site-Layout-Files\\HARV\\HarClip_UTMZ18.shp")

Comment: and still getting the error message

Comment: Error in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, as.character(options), quiet, type,  : 
  Open failed.

Comment: This is answered at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262505/python-cant-read-shapefile

Answer (score 3):

A "shapefile" is made up of several files with different extensions.

- **.shp**  -- this file contains the features' geometries.
- **.shx**  -- the spatial index
- **.dbf**  -- attribute values

The file will not open unless these files are all there.  It's a little misleading for ESRI to call it a shape**file** but there you have it.

You'll see a couple of others, such as **.prj** for spatial referencing and **.xml** for metadata but they are not required.

Your error was

```
Unable to open C:\Users\User\Documents\PlotLocations_HARV.shx
```

meaning that you couldn't open the spatial index file for some reason.

So solve the problem, you can make sure the ***.shx** file is in the same folder as the **.shp** file, or use the option `SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX` to regenerate the index.

You said "now I am good" so I assume that you found the file and moved it there, or regenerated the index.

Comment: How would you use the `SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX` option from R? I can't see it documented in `st_read()`. Incidentally, you can create the shx and other "shapefile" files by opeing and saving from OpenJump https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306218/creating-missing-shx-file

Comment: @MarkNeal `st_read` is a wrapper arounnd the GDAL function `CPL_read_ogr`; I suspect you could pass `options="--config SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX true"` into the call to `st_read`.

Comment: `st_read("my.shp",options="--config SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX true")` yielded this error message `1: In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  :
  GDAL Message 6: open option '--config SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX true' is not formatted with the key=value format` . Tried an `=` before the true which gave a different error message.

Comment: Great answer!  Just as soon as the 7-zip program was used to extract the other two files - (.shx, .dbf) from the zip file to join the lonely .shp file, the problem was solved.